# Apps Script - Get existing ListItem on FormApp

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to populate a ListItem inside a Form whith data from a SpreadSheet. Each row would be a choice.

So I have a ListItem question in my form and what I couldn't find out is: How can I acess an existing instance of a ListItem question in a form?

I have a :  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();, but how can I do something like "getFormAppListItem()"

And another doubt I have is... If I create a ListItem inside my function (addListItem() method), will it be recreated everytime someone opens the form (is a public survey)?

Comment: What do you want the end result to be?  Do you want the Form to be recreated every time someone opens the Form?  If the Form is opened in "view" mode, then there is no way to dynamically update or change the Form.  And you wouldn't want people opening up the Form in edit mode.  Do you want a Form personalized to each person who fills out the Form?

Comment: no, the same options/choices should appear to everyone. I just need the options to match a column in a spreadsheet.

Comment: So I need to pass the row values to the ListItem choices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var field1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(2,1).getValue;       
    var field2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(3,1).getValue;       
    var field3 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(4,1).getValue; 
    var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    var item = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
    item.setTitle('Choose the Pet you prefer').setChoices([
       item.createChoice(field1),
       item.createChoice(field2)
       item.createChoice(field3)
  ])
 .showOtherOption(true);
```

Please see the details here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item. Hope this helps.